# Alternate definition of the Dirac Delta function

Tags: definition, special-functions, dirac-delta

I was reading the [wikipedia article on the Dirac Delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), and what I saw was that the function needed to have a integral over the complete number line to be $1$, and have a value of zero everywhere except at $0$.

Now my idea is instead of defining the functions as:
$$\delta(x)=\lim_{b\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{|b|\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-(\frac{x}{b})^2}$$

Why can’t we take some other function whose value starts at $0$ at negative $\infty$, moves towards $0$ and suddenly changes value to $1$ and remains there? Then we can take the derivative of that function and the derivative would be the Delta function.

Now the function I used was the [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). My alternate definition for the Dirac Delta function is:
$$\delta(x)\overset{?}{=}\lim_{k\rightarrow{+\infty}}\frac{d}{dx}\sigma(kx)$$

It’s graph suggests that the definition might be correct. Am I right in thinking that this can be a suitable alternate definition?

Comment: Your definition works fine. The derivative of the sigmoid function is a nonnegative function with area 1 and in the limit $k\rightarrow\infty$ has support shrinking to the origin. Any such function is an approximation of the delta function.

Comment: @Deane Thanks a lot for the confirmation

Comment: @Deane is it common for the same function to have so varied definitions?

Comment: The definitions result in the same distribution. Your comment question is kind of like asking if it's weird that $\pi$ is both the limit of $(3,3.1,3.14,\ldots)$ and $(3,3.14,3.1415,\ldots)$? I guess I would answer that it's extremely common for mathematical objects to have multiple equivalent definitions.

Comment: There are many [limit representations](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/) of the Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$.

Comment: To elaborate on the previous two comments: 1) Any number is the limit of many different sequences. 2) Any function is the limit of many different sequences (or famlies) of functions. 3) The delta function is not even a function. It is a measure. There are many ways to approximate any measure by a sequence of functions.

Comment: To elaborate further on the previous comment by @Deane, the definition of $f_n(x)\to\delta(x)$ is $\forall \phi(x)\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}), \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x)\,\phi(x)\,dx\to \phi(0)$.

Comment: @StevenClark, that indeed is correct.

Comment: In distribution theory the Dirac delta distribution is not defined as the given limit. It is instead defined as a linear functional mapping a function $\varphi$ to $\varphi(0).$ The two limits in the question can be shown to converge to $\delta$ in the space of distributions.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, all my doubts are cleared now.